# Maven plugin removed is still usable

Tags: maven

I added to my maven project the a PMD and checkstyle plugins. And when I run them the work perfectly. But when I remove them from the pom.xml I can still run mvn checkstyle:checkstyle or mvn pmd:pmd even though I removed them. Also after removing them I ran mvn clean install. ANy idea of what could happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you execute are plugin goals (plugin:goal) and unlike "mvn install" not a phase.

you can run almost any plugin on a project if maven can find it. The apache maven plugins allow that shortcut notation (pmd:pmd) since maven will try to resolve them in the apache namespace.

Plugins from other sources would need to be run with their full name, for example:

```
org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.5:display-dependency-updates
```

The plugin itself decides if it can run a goal on its own or if it requires a running reactor and only works within the maven life-cycle (usually because it depends on outputs from other phases)

So in your case: `mvn install` should not run the pmd plugin anymore if its not in the pom - and install is a phase. `mvn pmd:pmd` will run it directly with its default config - since pmd:pmd is a plugin goal.

The default plugins per packaging and phase are documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/default-bindings.html). These may run if in the pom or not (depending on whats in the project).